# Android Firebase Phone Number Authentication Update Profile Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase with only the phone number authentication, using the FirebaseUI library to manage the authentication phase as shown below:

```
startActivityForResult(
AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
        .setAvailableProviders(
                Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()))
        .build(),
RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The activity result is handled by `onActivityResult` in this way:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            afterRegister(user);
            finish();
            return;
        } else {
            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {
                // User pressed back button
                ToastUtil.showSnackbar(this,R.string.sign_in_cancelled);
                return;
            }

            if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                ToastUtil.showSnackbar(this,R.string.no_internet_connection);
                return;
            }

            if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                ToastUtil.showSnackbar(this,R.string.unknown_error);
                return;
            }
        }

        ToastUtil.showSnackbar(this,R.string.unknown_sign_in_response);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do after the registration is to update the email and the display name on the FirebaseUser instance:

```
final String email = "myuser@email.com";
final FirebaseUser firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
firebaseUser.updateEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        boolean success = task.isSuccessful();
        if(!success){
            task.getException().printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

The update operation fails throwing that exception:

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException: 
This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.
```

My question is now: How can I "login again"? The documentation is poor about this specific case.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm curious about the solution :)

Comment: Still not :( I will use realtime database to store user information and not FirebaseUser

Answer (score 3):

Change email is sensitive info, if you catch exception **FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException** you must re-auth user with OTP, and back again to finish your task to update user email.
for me it's work.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.updateEmail(edEmail.text.toString())
            ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("UPDATE EMAIL", "User email address updated success.")
                }else{
                    try {
                        throw task.exception!!
                    } catch (e: FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException) {
                        /**
                         * handle this to re-auth User, e.g Open OTP page
                         * */
                    } catch (e: FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    } catch (e: FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

you can read how to update email with important notes in here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users